# Finding shorter indexed texts given long query phrase with Lucene?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene as a best effort match to map from user input to a long list of previous inputs for categorizing - and this works great -most- cases so far.

Problematic example:

Index:

- Ford
- Mercedes
- Honda
- I like toyota a lot

Input:

- ford (exact match: works great)
- toyota (partial match in a longer index entry: works great)
- i used to have a mercedes but now i dont however (longer text with a short exact match contained: will usually give either a long completely unrelated - fuzzy - match - or nothing)

I guess what I'm looking for is finding the longest common subsequence in case it's not one of the first two cases - but then again, I'm relatively new to Lucene, so maybe I just don't know enough search-lingo to explain it properly.

Answer (score 1):

What you might need is *n-gramm similarity*

see [NGramDistance](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/NGramDistance.html) class

**Edit** wikipedia link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching